# Unsatisfied link error in opencv in legacy Java app - Is this possible to correct without migrating to newer versions of opencv?

Tags: java, opencv, netbeans, javacv

I inherited a Java project from several years back that I need to make functional once again. It is a Java GUI app that relies on older opencv and Javacv versions (the older com.googlecode.javacv instead of the newer bytedeco versions). I have much of the application working but I cannot get past this error.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\AppData\Local\Temp\javacpp35316293606100\jniopencv_objdetect.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
```

I realize this is normally due to opencv not being present on java.library.path but I know that it is. I have tried many different locations on the path but none have had any effect. I have tried installing a newer version of opencv to C:\opencv and insuring that is on the path. This had no effect as well. I have also tried adding:

```
 System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
```

to the main class of the application and this also had no effect. I have scoured the web for a solution to this but this is really my last resort. I have researched every question on Stack Overflow that is even moderately related but none have resolved the issue.

Is it possible that this is javacpp related due to the older versions? I have tried to simply move on to the newer versions of opencv and javacv but there seem to be quite a few symbols missing from the bytedeco versions that were present in the googlecode versions. Any help would be so greatly appreciated! If there is any further info I can provide, please let me know!

Comment: The package names have changed a couple of times over the years, but otherwise the classes should be pretty much the same: http://bytedeco.org/news/2014/04/28/first-release/  http://bytedeco.org/news/2019/04/11/beyond-java-and-cpp/ Please let me know if you there's something missing though.

Comment: For example - to my knowledge IplImage doesnt exist in the newer versions of OpenCV and FrameGrabber doesnt exist in the newer versions of JavaCV ( I think this may have been moved to FFmpeg) but those do exist in the older googlecode implementations.

Comment: No, they both still exist: http://bytedeco.org/javacpp-presets/opencv/apidocs/org/bytedeco/opencv/opencv_core/IplImage.html http://bytedeco.org/javacv/apidocs/org/bytedeco/javacv/FrameGrabber.html If you'd like to try and debug the loading error instead: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/wiki/Debugging-UnsatisfiedLinkError-on-Windows

Comment: Thank you Samuel. Could you coach me on the placement of the dependencies code? Ive tried to place it in Main() but I get an error on the variable line of "Illegal start of expression" . Its this line -- String path = Loader.cacheResource(<module>.class, "windows-x86_64/jni<module>.dll").getPath();

Comment: I actually corrected that but I am now only getting a symbol not found error for cacheresources.

Comment: You'll need to put an existing class there...